# Parse title from .pls file (Shoutcast Radio Api)

Tags: java, android, file, parsing

I need to parse the title from .pls file i retrieved from Shoutcast. I am successfully able to parse the URL and tune into the radio.

The reason i need to parse the title is that whenever and API call is made to Shoutcast it return a file that may contain more than 1 URL for different station. I need to match the name of the radio station to the corresponding title in .pls file.

**Format of .pls file**

> [playlist]
>   numberofentries=4
>
> File1=http://***************
>
> Title1=(#1 - 13/1000) ::::..Radio Prahova Manele..:::Non-Stop <----
>
> Length1=-1
>
> File2=http:///***************
>
> Title2=(#2 - 24/1024) Radio Zuper FM - Zuper Muzica pe tot Internetul
>
> Length2=-1
>
> File3=http:///***************
>
> Title3=Radio Zuper FM - Zuper Muzica pe tot Internetul
>
> Length3=-1
>
> File4=http:///***************
>
> Title4=Radio Free Manele1
>
> Length4=-1
>
> Version=2

**This is how I tried to parse the Title from .pls file**

```
private String parseTitleFromLine(String line) {
    if (line == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String trimmed = line.trim();
    if (trimmed.indexOf("Title") >= 0) {
        return trimmed.substring(trimmed.indexOf("Title"));
    }
    return "";
}
```

Can someone suggest me how should I parse?

Answer (score 0):

The best way, in my opinion, would be to use regex:

This regex will match titles `Title\d+=(.*)` with the first group being the title

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Title\d+=(.*)")
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()){
    String title = m.group(1);
}
```

I haven't tested the above but it *should* work